# NSWindow does not resize according to NSSize returned from windowWillResize:toSize:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I am writing a Cocoa application for OS X in the style of Mail.app where there are 3 panes.  I'm achieving this by embedding one NSSplitView within another NSSplitView.  I'm trying to mimic the functionality of Mail.app that automatically collapses the leftmost pane when the window is resized to be smaller than a specific width.  I'm doing this using the following method of NSWindowDelegate

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
```

My implementation of this method is below but in short what is happening is that as the window is resized to be smaller the left pane does collapse as I would like however after it collapses the window should be allowed to continue to get smaller but the kicker is that it doesn't.  **The NSSize that I am returning during this process is correct but the window does not resize to match this value.**  I've checked to ensure that the NSWindow does not have any other minimum size limitations.  I'm stuck.  Can anybody help me understand what is causing this problem?

My implementation:

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
{
    CGFloat minWidth;
    if ([outerSplitView isSubviewCollapsed:leftPane])
    {
        minWidth = [outerSplitView dividerThickness] + MIDDLE_PANE_MINIMUM + [innerSplitView dividerThickness] + RIGHT_PANE_MINIMUM;
    }
    else
    {
        minWidth = LEFT_PANE_MINIMUM + [outerSplitView dividerThickness] + MIDDLE_PANE_MINIMUM + [innerSplitView dividerThickness] + RIGHT_PANE_MINIMUM;
    }

    if (![outerSplitView isSubviewCollapsed:leftPane])
    {
        // make sure the width is not smaller than current minimum width
        // find the difference proposed size and current size
        if (sender.frame.size.width - frameSize.width > LEFT_PANE_MINIMUM / 2.0 )
        {
            //Collapse the left pane.  Don't modify framesize.
            [outerSplitView setPosition:0.0 ofDividerAtIndex:0];
        }
        else if (frameSize.width < minWidth )
        {
            frameSize.width = minWidth;
        }
    }
    else if (frameSize.width < minWidth)
    {
        frameSize.width = minWidth;
    }

    return frameSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're not using auto layout. You might consider doing so. I think you'd get this behavior for free once you set the appropriate minimum width constraints and holding priorities on your subviews. (The minimum widths can be from explicit constraints directly on the subviews or they can result from the subviews within the subviews and their intrinsic sizes, etc.)

Given that your split views are both vertical, is there a reason that you didn't just use a single split view with three subviews? Once you have a split view in your UI, you can just drag another view into it to increase the number of panes.

Your logic for deciding when to collapse the view doesn't make sense to me. You have `if (sender.frame.size.width - frameSize.width > LEFT_PANE_MINIMUM / 2.0 )` which is determining if the user is attempting to drag by more than half the left pane's minimum. But how far the user has dragged isn't relevant. They may have started from a size much larger than the left pane's minimum.

I think you simply want to know if the proposed width is less than `LEFT_PANE_MINIMUM / 2.0 + [outerSplitView dividerThickness] + MIDDLE_PANE_MINIMUM + [innerSplitView dividerThickness] + RIGHT_PANE_MINIMUM`.

Also, since there's an absolute minimum width, you do always want to adjust the proposed `frameSize`. That is, even in the branch where you collapse the left pane you still want to enforce the minimum-width-when-the-left-pane-is-collapsed.

For example, try this logic:

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
{
    CGFloat minWidth = [outerSplitView dividerThickness] + MIDDLE_PANE_MINIMUM + [innerSplitView dividerThickness] + RIGHT_PANE_MINIMUM;
    CGFloat minUncollapsedWidth = LEFT_PANE_MINIMUM + minWidth;
    CFGloat forceCollapseWidth = LEFT_PANE_MINIMUM / 2.0 + minWidth;

    if (![outerSplitView isSubviewCollapsed:leftPane])
    {
        if (frameSize.width < forceCollapseWidth)
        {
            //Collapse the left pane.
            [outerSplitView setPosition:0.0 ofDividerAtIndex:0];
        }
        else if (frameSize.width < minUncollapsedWidth)
        {
            frameSize.width = minUncollapsedWidth;
        }
    }

    if (frameSize.width < minWidth)
    {
        frameSize.width = minWidth;
    }

    return frameSize;
}
```

If that still doesn't let the window continue resizing smaller, then:

1. If you stop dragging and then start again, does that work? That
   is, is the problem just with a continuous resize operation *during
   which* the left pane collapsed, or is it that the window will never
   allow itself to go smaller than what I've called
   `minUncollapsedWidth`?
2. How have you determined that there's nothing else limiting the window's size? What did you check?

Comment: Ken - thank you so much for your detailed response.  Unfortunately your implementation did not seem to make any difference.  The left pane still collapsed at the appropriate time but the window did not continue to resize after the collapse.  The answer to your 1st question is No - If I stop dragging and then start dragging again the window still won't get any smaller even though the width component of frameSize that is returned is less than the current frame size.  To answer your 2nd question I looked in the NSWindow's properties in interface builder and ensured that there was no minimum width

Comment: Was I correct that you're not using auto layout? Are you using a window title bar accessory, a stack view, or some other view that may be enabling auto layout for your window and establishing a constraint that leads to a minimum width? You could try logging `[window.contentView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]` at some point after you're sure layout has occurred. If you comment out your `-windowWillResize:toSize:` method, does the window allow resizing to a smaller width? Are you sure that `LEFT_PANE_MINIMUM` is non-zero?